# Postgresql: run SQL query script and export to csv

Tags: postgresql, csv

I am running Postgresql version 9.3 on Ubuntu. I am wondering if there is a way to run a select statement stored in a script on a Postgres database and then send the results to csv. I know how to do either of the two by themselves; for example, exporting to csv (with the query explicitly written out):

```
COPY(select * from mytable) to 'path/to/file.csv' with csv header;
```

and running an sql script:

```
\i 'myscript.sql'
```

But after searching around I could not figure out how to do both in one action. That is, I could not figure out how to export to a csv when running a query script rather than typing out a select statement manually.

Comment: could you try explaining what you want a little better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\set query `cat /path/to/myscript.sql`
copy (:query) to '/path/to/file.csv' with csv header;
```

[SQL Interpolation in psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html)

Comment: make sure you do not have `;` in myscript.sql and you have write permission to the folder where csv file will be exported.